# Regular expression further checking

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a regular expression that would check a string,Is it a function or not.
My regular expression for checking that as follows:

```
regex=r' \w+[\ ]*\(.*?\)*'
```

It succefully checks whether the string contains a function or not.
But it grabs normal string which contains firs barcket value,such as "test (meaning of test)".

So I have to check further that if there is a space between function name and that brackets that will not be caught as match.So I did another checking as follows:

```
regex2=r'\s'
```

It work successfully and can differentiate between "test()" and "test ()".
But now I have to maintain another condition that,if there is no space after the brackets(eg. test()abcd),it will not catch it as a function.The regular expression should only treat as match when it will be like "test() abcd".
But I tried using different regular expression ,unfortunately those are not working.
Her one thing to mention the checking string is inserted in to a list at when it finds a match and in second step it only check the portion of the string.Example:
**String : This is a python function test()abcd**
At first it will check the string for function and when find matches with function test()
then send only "test()" for whether there is a gap between "test" and "()".
In this  last step I have to find is there any gap between "test()" and "abcd".If there is gap it will not show match as function otherwise as a normal portion of string.
How should I write the regular expression for such case?

The regular expression will have to show in following cases:

```
1.test() abc
2.test(as) abc
3.test()
```

will not treat as a function if:

```
1.test (a)abc
2.test ()abc
```

Comment: are you trying to match python functions? If so, are you trying to match the definition or the call?

Comment: No,I am trying to match mainly C style function,and the regex matches all type of function.Both cases function and the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\w+\([^)]*\))(\s+|$)
```

Bascially you make sure it ends with either spaces or end of line.

BTW the kiki tool is very useful for debugging Python re: http://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/

Answer (score 0):

```
regex=r'\w+\([\w,]+\)(?:\s+|$)'
```

Comment: I tried with  regex=r'\w+\s+\\([\w,]+?\\)\s+' but it can not catch "function test()"

Comment: the space after `test` is now optional

Comment: actually its should find match in the cases: function test(),test(),test(a),test(a)aas, should not catch test (),test()asa.

Comment: why will test(a)aas be valid but test()asa will be invalid?

Comment: this is confusing. you just mentioned in your comment that test(a)aas is valid. can you make up your mind?

Comment: ow!sorry that will be "test(a) aas"

Comment: please edit your question and state in tabular form which is valid and invalid for your use case. it will help us help you a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem at first I just chexked for the string that have "()"using the regular expression:

```
regex = r' \w+[\ ]*\(.*?\)\w*'
```

Then for checking the both the space between function name and brackets,also the gap after the brackets,I used following function with regular expression:

```
       def testFunction(self, func):
            a=" "
            func=str(func).strip()
            if  a in func:
                return False
            else:   
                a = re.findall(r'\w+[\ ]*', func)
                j = len(a)
                if j<=1:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
```

So it can now differentiate between "test() abc" and "test()abc".
Thanks